# Reverse proxy returning page not found (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: proxy, url-rewriting, reverse, arr

I am having two websites (ASP.NET MVC) on my local PC. One is site1.com and the second one is site2.com. I want site1.com/blog to be served from site2.com using URL rewrites.

When I put http://site1.com/blog/home/about (home/about exists on site2.com) in the address bar I get a 404. Even the example here doesn't work on my PC:http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

But there I get a 500 instead of a 404. Still can't tell where the problem is even when looking at the request trace log.

Update:
I was able to make the example work by removing the compression. This line helped:

```html
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
```

Now it is obvious the problem is related to ASP.NET MVC but can't find a solution to it. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Update2:
Oddly enough the ignore route (for the rewritten part) solution doesn't work. Although some people said for them it worked.

Thank you!